# How to populate the table view cell with values entered in another view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell, which consists of four labels and an image view. I have another `UIViewController` which consists of two text fields and one text view.

When the values are entered in the text fields and text view of this controller, and the save button is pressed, the values must be saved on to my custom table view cells' text labels. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the Values entered in the Text Inputs and save them in different NSString variables. Set those values for the Next ViewControllers Input.

For example, declare a NSString in second View Controller Interface and @synthesize that. Before moving from first controller to second controller, set the value for that respective variable.

Answer (score 3):

**Update your data source object with the values** and call `reloadData` function on tableview instance

```
- (void)reloadData
```

Call as below

```
[myTableView  reloadData];
```

**EDITED:**

**First :** you could use the [delegate concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Objective-C_example) of Objective-C,

**Second:** you could store the text value in user default using `NSUserDefault` and access that in other view controller,

See the very good blog post on NSUserDefault .

[iPhone Programming Tutorial – Saving/Retrieving Data Using NSUserDefaults](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)

Comment: actually she is asking how to pass the values from one view to the another view